# OSL EventBoolFlag/Write text file

Tags: osl

I use Open Shading Language.
I need save event (if (speed_particle > 0.5) {boolean_flag = 1}).

The trouble is that the variable "flag" is **reset** every frame!

How can i save the value of the variable "flag"?
Or
How can i save the value of the variable **in the file**?
(How can i write file using the Open Shading Language?)